# How do I declare a public function in Laravel 8 Base Controller

Tags: php, laravel-8

am getting the following syntax error,   unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file when running this code from Microsoft PHP Graph Tutorial.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=1)

```
public function loadViewData(){
  $viewData = [];

  // Check for flash errors
  if (session('error')) {
    $viewData['error'] = session('error');
    $viewData['errorDetail'] = session('errorDetail');
  }

  // Check for logged on user
  if (session('userName')) {
    $viewData['userName'] = session('userName');
    $viewData['userEmail'] = session('userEmail');
    $viewData['userTimeZone'] = session('userTimeZone');
  }

  return $viewData;
}
```

( I am relatively inexperienced php person, trying to learn laravel and link to Microsoft Graph. There are many tutorials for linking to Microsoft but none of them work as far as I can see, most are out of date. This was my best hope.

Code not working: note line below is one causing problem. If remove 'public;' then no errors are reported in VSCode

i.e. Note in VSCode it reports no errors in the file if public is removed. As soon as you add it back in you get '

Comment: You need to show where exactly you've added this piece of code.

Comment: Seems you are adding this piece of code outside `class xxx {}`

Comment: @Felippe - amazing - you fixed it! @ El_Vanja tahnks also

Answer (score 0):

As per the the code is correct but you need to check the class of curly brackets properly close or not .

1 ) when you are using the class and no closing curly brackets properly that time it's given error like unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file .

```
class yourController extends Controller {

   public function loadViewData(){
     $viewData = [];

     // Check for flash errors
   if (session('error')) {

     $viewData['error'] = session('error');
     $viewData['errorDetail'] = session('errorDetail');

    }

   // Check for logged on user
   if (session('userName')) {

   $viewData['userName'] = session('userName');
   $viewData['userEmail'] = session('userEmail');
   $viewData['userTimeZone'] = session('userTimeZone');

  }

 return $viewData;
```

}
}